# Difficulty removing extra piano chords from piano made with HTML5,CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a piano made with html5,CSS and Java Script. The piano has 24 chords and want to reduce it to 9 white chords along with their respective black chordsi.e from [C-D'], I am not good at java script and tried my best to remove those keys and to a certain level suceeded in excluding those desired chords but they are still present in the canvas and do not respond to click events but apart from being excluded i want them to disappear from the canvas ie chords from [C to D'].
i am attaching the html and js source code below.

Here is the HTML code:

**Index.html**

```js
var Chords = [
  [ "Single Note", [1] ]];



var Piano = (function()
{
 var $chordSelector = $("#chordSelector");
 var $chordsInplay = $("#chordsInplay");
 var $canvas = $("#c"); 
 var context = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

 var gaps = [3,7,10,14]
  , jumpTable = [2,3,5,6,7,9,10,12,13,14]
  , eb = [2,4,7,9,11,14,16,19,21,23];
 var xOffset = 1, yOffset = 1;

 var chords = "C C# D D# E F F# G G# A A# B C' C#' D'";

 this.chordsArray = chords.split(" ");

 //Constructorish

 context.strokeStyle = "black";
 context.fillStyle = "white";
 
 $.each(Chords, function (i,v)
 {
  $chordSelector.append("<option value='"  + v[0] + "'>"  + v[0] + "</option>");
 });
 $.each(this.chordsArray, function (i,v)
 {
  $chordsInplay.append("<audio src=\"resources/"  +  escape(v) + ".mp3\" preload='auto'></audio>");
 });
 //Public methods
 this.drawPiano = function (selectedKeys) 
 {
  var selectedKeys = selectedKeys || [];
  var key = 1, skipped = 0;

  keyLooper(selectedKeys, drawIvoryKey, null);
  keyLooper(selectedKeys, null, drawEbonyKey);
 };


 //Private methods

 var keyLooper = function(selectedKeys, beforeSkipHandler, afterSkipHandle)
 {
  var key = 0, skipped = 0;
  while (key < 28) 
  {
   if (beforeSkipHandler != null)  //assume function
    beforeSkipHandler.call(this, selectedKeys, key, skipped);
   if (gaps.indexOf((key % 14) + 1) < 0)
   {
    skipped++;
    if (afterSkipHandle!= null)  //assume function
     afterSkipHandle.call(this, selectedKeys, key, skipped);
   }
   key++;
  }
 };
    
 var getDefaultColorForKey = function (key)
 {
  return key >= 14 ? "grey" : "black";
 }
 
 var drawEbonyKey = function(selectedKeys, key, skipped)
 {
  var keyX = (key * 30) + xOffset;
  var letterx = (key * 30) + 21; 
  var drawingKey = (key + 1) + skipped;

  
  context.fillStyle = (selectedKeys.indexOf(drawingKey) > -1) ? "#CEF" : getDefaultColorForKey(key);
  context.fillRect(keyX + 20 ,yOffset,20, 75);

  context.strokeRect(keyX + 20 ,yOffset,20,75);
  context.fillStyle = (selectedKeys.indexOf(drawingKey) > -1) ? "black" : "white";
  context.fillText(chordsArray[key + skipped], keyX + 22, yOffset + 40);
  context.fillStyle = getDefaultColorForKey(key)
 };

 var drawIvoryKey = function(selectedKeys, key, skipped)
 {
  var keyX = (key * 30) + xOffset;
  var letterx = (key * 30) + 11 + xOffset;
  var drawingKey = (key + 1) + skipped;

  context.fillStyle = (selectedKeys.indexOf(drawingKey) > -1) ? "#CEF" : "white";
  context.fillRect(keyX ,yOffset,30,150);
    
  context.strokeRect(keyX ,yOffset,30,150);
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillText(this.chordsArray[(key) + skipped], letterx  , yOffset + 110);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
 }


 var isInRect = function (x,y,rx,ry,rw,rh)
 {
  return (x >= rx && x <= rx+rw) && (y >= ry && y <= ry+rh);
 };
 var isInPiano = function(x,y)
 {
  return isInRect(x,y,xOffset,yOffset,420,150);
 };

 var findIvoryKey = function (x, y)
 {
    var key = Math.ceil((x - xOffset) / 30)
  if (jumpTable.indexOf(key) > -1)
  {
   key = key + (jumpTable.indexOf(key) + 1);
  }
  else {
   for (var i = 0;key > 1 && i<jumpTable.length;i++) {
    if (jumpTable[i] > key)
    {
     key = key + i;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  return key;
 }
 var actuallyOnEbonyKey = function(key, x, y)
 {
  x = x - xOffset, y = y - yOffset;
  var m = (x % 30);
  var k = key;

  if ((y >= 75) || (m > 10 && m < 20))
   return key;

  ((m >= 10 || m == 0) ? k++ : k--);

  return eb.indexOf(k) < 0 ? key : k;
 }
 
 var getChordKeysForRootKey = function(key)
 {
  var selectedChord = $("#chordSelector option:selected").val();
  var keys = [key];
  for (var i = 0; i < Chords.length; i++)
  {
   if (Chords[i][0] == selectedChord)
   {
    keys = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < Chords[i][1].length; c++)
    {
     keys.push(Chords[i][1][c] + (key - 1));
    }
    break;
   }
  }
   
  return keys;
 }
 
 
 var mouseMoveHandler = function(e)
 {      
  var x = Math.floor((e.pageX-$("#c").offset().left));
  var y = Math.floor((e.pageY-$("#c").offset().top));
  if (!isInPiano(x,y))
   return;

  var key = findIvoryKey(x, y);
  key = actuallyOnEbonyKey(key, x, y); 
  
  var keys = getChordKeysForRootKey(key);
  
  this.drawPiano(keys);

 };
 
 this.playNotes = function (selectedKeys)
 {
  selectedKeys = selectedKeys || [];
  if (selectedKeys.length == 0)
   return;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedKeys.length; i++)
  {
    var a = $chordsInplay.append("<audio src='resources/"+ escape(this.chordsArray[selectedKeys[i] - 1]) +".mp3' autoplay='true'></audio>");
    a.find("audio:last").bind("ended", function (e) 
    { 
     $(this).remove(); 
    });
  } 
 }
 
 
 var mouseClickHandler = function(e)
 {      
  var x = Math.floor((e.pageX-$("#c").offset().left));
  var y = Math.floor((e.pageY-$("#c").offset().top));
  if (!isInPiano(x,y))
   return;

  var key = findIvoryKey(x, y);
  key = actuallyOnEbonyKey(key, x, y); 
  var keys = getChordKeysForRootKey(key);
  this.playNotes(keys);

 };

 //REGISTER EVENTS

 $("#c").mousemove($.proxy(mouseMoveHandler, this));
 $("#c").click($.proxy(mouseClickHandler, this));


 //KICK OFF 
 this.drawPiano();
})();
```

```css
#header, 
#midsection,
#content,
canvas
{
 width:844px;
 margin:auto;
}
*
{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
}
h1
{
 font-size:64px;
 color:black;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top:1px;
 margin-bottom:1px;
}
h1 span
{
 display:inline-block;
 padding-top:-10px;
}
#header 
{
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
#header img {
 margin-top:10px;
 float:left;
}
canvas
{
 display:inline;
 background: transparent;   
}

{


}

#content
{

}
select 
{
 float:right;
 margin:auto;
 display:block;
 margin-top:30px;
}

body {
 background: url('resources/background-site.jpg') top center repeat-x;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
canvas {
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>HTML5 Piano</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="piano.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
   <select id="chordSelector"></select>
  </div>
  <div id="midsection">
   
   <canvas id="c" width="844" height="180"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <div id="chordsInplay">
   
   </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chords.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="piano.js"></script>
 </body> 
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyLooper function is hard-coded to produce 28 keys:

```
while (key < 28) ...
```

You'll need to change that to reduce the number of keys it draws.

Comment: Almost. The keys are drawn in pairs and OP is wanting to draw half of one of those pairs.

Comment: @martin It helped  but theres one extra black chord thats left how do i remove it too and also when i decrease the numbet to 9 and decrease the canvas size to 550*180 the piano chords dont respond properly to click events why is it so?

Comment: For the black key, you'll need to add some code to this.drawPiano to detect when it's drawing the last white key and not add the accompanying black one. As for the size, I can't test it right now, but you should look at findIvoryKey and actuallyOnEbonyKey. The calculations for var m are hard-coded to divide the canvas into 30 slices, when for your purposes I believe it should be 11 if you're maintaining the original spacing.